Unable to install IOS app which built on azure devops pipeline with Xcode task
We are planning to move from app center to azure devops pipelines so planning to create iOS mobile builds in azure devops, but I can able to create ipa file with Xcode task but I’m unable to install, using same certificate and provisioning profile which I used for app center. Appreciate for your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
